# Trouble passing json file to AWS autoscaling create-launch-configuration --block-device-mapping

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, autoscaling

currently the command looks like something like this

```
aws autoscaling create-launch-configuration --block-device-mapping file://mappings.json
```

and within the mappings.json is

```
{
  "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
  "Encrytped":false,
  "DeleteOnTermination":true,
  "Ebs": {
     "VolumeSize":300,
     "VolumeType":"gp2"
  }
}
```

the error the command gives

```
Error parsing parameter '--block-device-mappings': Invalid JSON: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2(char 1)
JSON received: {
```

note i'm running this cmd on windows subsystem.

I've tried escaping every " within the mappings.json with \ and it didn't work

Comment: Your question actually helped solve my problem! I was working off an example without the "file://" prefix on the json filename and trying to troubleshoot the error "Error parsing parameter '--block-device-mappings': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:
mapping.json". Adding file:// fixed it, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `block-device-mappings` should be a list:

```
[{
  "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
  "Encrytped": false,
  "DeleteOnTermination": true,
  "Ebs": {
     "VolumeSize": 300,
     "VolumeType": "gp2"
  }
}]
```

Please note, that there are still many other information missing (or not given in the question) for the command to work. Thus just fixing the `block-device-mappings` will not lead to successful execution of the command.